# mod_auth_token for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, hotlinking, auth-token

Is there a Tomcat Servlet that works similar to [mod_auth_token](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/)?

`mod_auth_token` is written in C, mean for Apache. I am looking for a pure Java implementation.

It is better if that implementation extends the Tomcat DefaultServlet, which supports gzip, etags etc.,